# 1054 error with nested query with right join

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to display a count of tickets per staff member while showing current tickets.

```
SELECT s.firstname, s.lastname, t.ticket_id, o.id, t.created FROM ost_ticket t
JOIN ost_staff s ON t.staff_id = s.staff_id
JOIN ost_user u ON t.user_id = u.id
JOIN ost_organization o ON u.org_id = o.id
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(tt.ticket_id) 
    FROM ost_ticket tt) a ON t.ticket_id = a.ticket_id WHERE...
```

I'm getting a Error in query (1054):

> Unknown column 'a.ticket_id' in 'on clause'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select `ticket_id` in the subquery if you want to refer to it on the outside.

```
RIGHT JOIN 
(
  SELECT ticket_id, COUNT(ticket_id) as cnt
  FROM ost_ticket 
  GROUP BY ticket_id
) a ON t.ticket_id = a.ticket_id
```